# Browser portability problems

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a problem with my CSS on [a website I'm working on](http://www.midiamantedegel.com).
For some reason the website's CSS works for FF 3 and IE 7 but of course MS complicates things as this doesn't work for IE 6.
The header looks squashed.
The trouble is that my client owns IE 6 and I was yelled at without knowing why.
My questions are:

1. Where can I get a test suite for all browsers?
2. How do I fix it? Can someone test it for me?

Here is the CSS for IE:

```
/* CSS Document */

#presentation{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 689px;
height: 586px;
z-index: 0;
}

#pretext{
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
}

#cleft{
width:97px;
height:665px;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#cright{
width:97px;
height:665px;
position: relative;
float: right;
}
```

Here is the html:
EDIT SO messes up with html.
Here is [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f4ebd88d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first problem: I'd recommend using a browser-specific style sheet.

Since you're using XHTML, you could use the following:

```
  <!--[if lte IE 6]><link href="lte-ie-6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><![endif]-->
```

The CSS file `lte-ie-6.css` would then only be read by IE6. You can use it to easily override other CSS that causes visual mishaps in IE6.

---

There is software, such as [MultipleIE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE), [Internet Explorer Collection](http://codecpack.nl/iecollection.htm) and [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), that can emulate different versions of IE. However, this doesn't always give accurate results. Microsoft's official answer to your last question would be: [install Virtual PC and run IE6 on it](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/11/30/ie6-and-ie7-running-on-a-single-machine.aspx).

Lately, Microsoft has been working on SuperPreview, an official website preview utility that does the same, but with reliable results. [Read about SuperPreview](http://blogs.msdn.com/xweb/archive/2009/03/18/Microsoft-Expression-Web-SuperPreview-for-Windows-Internet-Explorer.aspx) and/or [download it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en).

Comment: Hmm useful.
I know about the CSS comment IF that works only on IE.
I still don't have a clue on the CSS itself though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to test it yourself :)

Comment: Just as any other unofficial IE emulator, IETester might display inaccurate results (i.e. other results than users with genuine IE6 installations would experience). Use with caution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862284/browser-portability-problems/862361#862361

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no easy answer to this problem. My advise to you is this:

1. Code using the smallest set of techniques you need to do what you want.
2. Make your code standards compliant.
3. Do at least some testing in each browser (+version) you need to support.
4. Write a letter of Complaint to Steve Balmer of Microsoft about IE. (Every self respecting web developer should do this).

Regards

Comment: It is standards compliant as far as I can see but it still doesn't work.
Is there a way you can fix the CSS easily for me?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of browser CSS quirks. It is difficult indeed to get a nice working CSS based website that's consistent across browsers. You'll need to experiment a lot.

Sometimes you may be better off using a CSS framework like [BlueprintCSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)

Try viewing your site in various browsers under various platforms by using the [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) service.

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) lets you easily install/run multiple versions of IE side by side.

Comment: Just as any other unofficial IE emulator, Multiple IE might display inaccurate results (i.e. other results than users with genuine IE6 installations would experience). Use with caution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862284/browser-portability-problems/862361#862361

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look and one of your stylesheets set the height and width for #logopic

```
#logopic{
width: 50%;
height: auto;
vertical-align:bottom;}
```

Try the real hight and width of the image in there instead

```
width:699px;
height:126px;
```